# How to send emails in Swift using Mailgun

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, swift, mailgun

I have the need to send automatic emails in a Swift project I'm working on. So far my best lead seems to be using Mailgun. (I'm open to better options if anyone has liked something else)

Swift is not listed in the Mailgun API Reference in their documentation, and I didn't see objective-c either. The only article speaking at all about his I've found is this [one](http://blog.mailgun.com/objective-c-mailgun-sdk-now-available/).

**Update**

I've been trying to piece together everything and this is where I've gotten so far.

I was able to get Mailgun installed via cocoapods. Using it in Swift has been kinda tricky.

I setup cocoapods with the following pod file:

```
target 'TestApp' do
pod 'mailgun', '~> 1.0.3'
end

target 'TestAppTests' do
end
```

With this podfile I was able to run pod install and set up the dependencies. Then I setup an Objective-C-Bridging Header in build settings. I used the following objective-C bridging header.

```
#ifndef Promises_Promises_Bridging_Header_h
#define Promises_Promises_Bridging_Header_h
#import <mailgun/Mailgun.h>
#import "testMail.h"
#endif
```

I was getting a linking error for awhile, but I needed to have the project opened via the workspace and I had to go to *Product -> Schemes -> Edit Schemes* and add the Pods-mailgun to the top of the list and then it would let me build.

Now I want to take advantage of the MailGun API. The docs say to do the following.

```
Mailgun *mailgun = [Mailgun clientWithDomain:@"samples.mailgun.org" apiKey:@"key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"];

[mailgun sendMessageTo:@"Jay Baird <jay.baird@rackspace.com>" 
                  from:@"Excited User <someone@sample.org>" 
               subject:@"Mailgun is awesome!" 
                  body:@"A unicode snowman for you! ☃"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I've answered my own question. The process isn't too terrible. Install mailgun using cocoapods.
Link the objective-c code that is needed using an objective-c bridging header.
Create an objective c file to house your method that will call the mailgun operation, and use it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <mailgun/Mailgun.h>

@interface mailTest: NSObject
- (void) sendMail: (NSString*)email;

@end
```

Then in my swift code I just call:

```
            var test: mailTest = mailTest()
            test.sendMail("testemail@testemail.com")
```

Here is the mailTest header file. I created a .m file that implements the sendMail method and calls the code from the API and it works great. The only other thing that could be challenging is setting up the mailgun account and configuring your domain so that emails can be sent, but that isn't code related.

Answer (score 2):

I think i am facing exactly the same problem with you. But I am a little confused on how many .h and .m files you have used and what each one contains. I am clueless on obj C so I try to follow you blindly.

Correct me if I am wrong.

• You have one .h bridging header file that contains:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import <mailgun/Mailgun.h>
```

• You have one .m file that contains:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <mailgun/Mailgun.h>

@interface mailTest: NSObject
- (void) sendMail: (NSString*)email;

@end
```

• And in your Viewcontroller.swift you have (lets say in a button) this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
    var test: mailTest = mailTest()
    test.sendMail("testemail@testemail.com")
}
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: In my naivety I originally made this overcomplicated. I thought I could only access objective-c methods via an objective-c class, which wasn't needed at all. Objective-C and Swift are both backwards and forwards compatible. So simply import "#import <mailgun/Mailgun.h>" in your bridging header, and you can call the Mailgun method just like you would a swift method! EX: var mailgun = Mailgun.clientWithDomain(...). Also, I didn't downvote your question, to me it seems pretty well formatted, but maybe someone was upset you asked a question as an answer. Idk, Bad luck I guess. Hope this helps +1

Comment: Sweet, traditionally in stack we upvote when something is helpful ;) @Tromos

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind. In fact I was keeping track of the people that assisted me in my work. Since I am a new user I needed more rep to be able to do that. Today this feature was unlocked for me, so here you go :)

Answer (score 2):

There's another option that you could try if you wanted as much as possible to be on the Swift side:

1. If you don't have a bridging header yet, create a dummy objective-c file (add new file to project). Xcode will ask if you will like to add a header file (this will sort out the header for you automatically)
2. Add this to your bridging header (providing you already imported mail gun using cocoa pods):
   `#import "mailgun/Mailgun.h"`
3. Import maligun in your swift class:
   `import mailgun`
4. Simply use mailgun's API in swift as you would in Objective-C:

   ```
   @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {

       let mailgun = Mailgun.client(withDomain: "samples.mailgun.org", apiKey: "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0")

       mailgun?.sendMessage(to: "Jay Baird <jay.baird@rackspace.com>", from: "Excited User <someone@sample.org>", subject: "Mailgun is awesome!", body: "A unicode snowman for you! ☃")

   }
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to send same message to multiple recipients?